# Maven release:prepare doesn't change <tag>

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am using `mvn release:prepare` to bump version numbers on my project. I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:code.stuff.com/scm/project/repo.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@code.stuff.com:7999/project/repo.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

When I run `release:prepare`, everything seems to work, but the tagged commit still has `<tag>HEAD</tab>` in the POM. Isn't this supposed to be changed to the git tag? I also see a message near the beginning of the output: `[INFO] Not generating release POMs`.

Am I doing something wrong?

I am using Maven 3.3.3.

Comment: Did you already run with `-X`?

Comment: Hm, no I hadn't. When adding `-X`, I see a line that looks suspicious: `[DEBUG] ScmTagPhase :: scmTagParameters scmRevision null`, but I'm not sure why that would be null.

Comment: Not sure if that has to do with the pom or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had been using the included version of maven-plugin-release. When I added an explicit version number to the pom.xml as described in the documentation:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
```

This fixed the problem. My theory is that it had something to do with not reading git's output correctly.